# Render Diamond with Alpha Channel to composite (Octane Renderer)

Tags: transparency, octane-render-engine

I am doing a diamond jewelry render, using Octane's plugin for Blender. The resultant renders are very good, but I am having trouble manipulating the color of the metal through the diamond.

As an introduction, since diamond jewelry is not a product that most people will end up rendering everyday, diamond jewelry, would have diamonds (will act like glass, with a IOR of 2.419) set/studded in a metal (glossy material). At certain angles (as can be seen in the image, marked with yellow) the diamond would act almost like a transparent glass, i.e. the metal under/behind it would be visible.

The client I am rendering for, requires that I render and provide him 4 views with 3 different colors (white, yellow and rose/pink, for the colors of gold that a piece of jewelry can be made in).

Ideally I would like to render out 1 x 4views (so 4 images) and the use blender's compositor to manipulate the color of the metal, to produce the other colors of the metal as needed. This way I would save having to render 12 images. While changing the color of the metal is easy, I am unable to change the color of the metal that is visible through the diamond (again marked in yellow)

Is there a method I do not know of, which would allow me to change the color of the metal itself and what it appears through the diamond (i.e. through refraction)

The color of the metal is only for dramactic effect (and to make the problem I am facing more obvious)

[image]

Comment: I doubt that you will find an accurate way to just do this in post. You are dealing with very complex materials (as you probably know, given that you chose to render in octane to bypass the limitations of blender's render engines). The gems' quality is based on the many properties of the material transparency, translucency, refraction, dispersion, reflection etc... It would be hard to separate those many passes, to color correct and then calculate how the many interactions are at play recombine later in a way that would be satisfying to an expert in gems and jewelry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was thinking that it would be a bit far fetched to assume I could manipulate the color of the metal seen through the diamond, but could not hurt to ask, never know if a simple command exists!